# Error with Set-AzSqlServerAudit PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use the **Set-AzSqlServerAudit** PowerShell command as follows:

```
Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "My_RG" -ServerName "My_Server" -BlobStorageTargetState Enabled -StorageAccountResourceId "XXXXXX" -RetentionInDays 365 -PredicateExpression "[database_principal_name]= 'dbo' OR ([action_name] = 'DATABASE AUTHENTICATION FAILED' OR [action_name] = 'CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION' OR [action_name] = 'ALTER SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION' OR [action_name] = 'DROP SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION')"
```

If I limit the PredicateExpression parameter to `"[database_principal_name]= 'dbo'"` then it works fine, but using the expression I want results in the following error:

```
 Set-AzSqlServerAudit : One or more errors occurred. At line:1 char:1
 + Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "My_RG" -ServerName "My_Serv...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzSqlServerAudit], AggregateException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Auditing.Cmdlet.SetAzSqlServerAudit
```

Comment: The Predicate Expression is the WHERE clause of an SQL Server.  I usually recommend testing queries in SQL Server Management Studio where the error message are very good.  You really do not need the parenthesis.  I suspect your error is due to query not retuning any results.  To debug you can add one OR at a time until you find error. Make sure the column action_name exists in the database.

Comment: @paulH I have the same problem, did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @MatiasK - Sorry I didn't.  I gave up and went with just checking for dbo.  If you find a solution then let me know! :-)